# Prevent CGI Timeout in Apache with PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, fastcgi, cgi

I have a PHP process which the user runs in the browser, but tends to take a fairly long time - upwards of 5 minutes. We just switched to a new server, and when we try to run the script now, it consistently times out at 4 minutes exactly, sending to a 500 Internal Server Error page and outputting the following errors in the error log:

> Timeout waiting for output from CGI
>   script
>
> Premature end of script headers:
>   cgi_wrapper

What's interesting is that the PHP process does seem to complete in the background. If we navigate away from the 500 Error page and wait a bit, the desired changes from the script do get made.

Is there any way to unhinge this CGI limit which seems to have been placed on us? I have read about FastCGI, but am not sure how to install this on our server (Apache, centOS, PHP 5.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to solve the problem - HTTP is not intended to handle operations taking a very long time - while it sounds like your current PHP config is allowing the program to run for a long time this implies that you've misconfigured it - it should know when the webserver drops the conenction and respond appropriately. It might be possible to fudge the webserver config, and even to get a browser to stay connected for long enough, and maybe you don't have to worry about proxies in between - but you're using each of the tools in a way they were not designed to be used.

The right way to solve the problem is to start it from a web page, [but running is a seperate process group](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html&rct=j&q=argh%20symcbean%20long%20running%20php%20process&ei=X9SaTe_iJs_sOZ6Z3JMH&usg=AFQjCNEn3nHVOwzSRJ3HtgEgDSsOKPu4kw&sig2=BnT8eJ0OVe6TlamGLQngSg&cad=rja) and add in code to the long running process to write the status somewhere which can then be polled by a script triggered from the browser.